# Running Selenium scripts on Bluemix

Tags: selenium, ibm-cloud

I am completely new to testing and Bluemix. As per my requirement, I need to run Selenium scripts on Bluemix. I am using Automated Accessibility Tester service in Bluemix for running Selenium scripts. I have added the service to my space and added the `aat.jar` and the Tool Configuration JSON  file to my working directory. I have added some scripts to my test case for running on remote server. However, I am getting the following error message:

> error Message: setEnabledIds INFO: Enabled Rulesets: IBM_DCP080115
>   FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.

This is the script that I have added:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ComplianceConfig config = new ComplianceConfig(new String[] { "IBM_DCP080115" });
driver = ComplianceDriverRemote.init(config, capabilities);
```

I am getting an error at `driver = ComplianceDriverRemote.init(config, capabilities);` 
For running test cases on Bluemix, I am following this link: 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ecsdashboard/index.html

Comment: This message usually appears when the chromedriver.exe does not support the chrome browser version. In the link you have mentioned there is no mention of the path to chromedriver.exe system property which is required for automation with Chrome. What is the aat.jar contents?

Comment: Actually I dont know what we have exactly in aat.jar, as I said before I was following this link https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ecsdashboard/index.html
here in one of the step they mention to add aat.jar
I guess aat.jar and tool configure JSON file contains the details of bluemix which may help full at the time of running test cases on bluemix

And @Gras shopper I was also strucked at IBM_DCP080115, what is IBM_DCP080115 and why we are using it.

It would be great if you could help me out.